# Silverlight with mvc or Ria Services?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have an Asp.net MVC application which uses html5 and jquery on the client side. Management want to experiment with Silverlight as they feel it will give the end user the impression they are running a desktop application rather than web based application.

What I want is to create a silverlight version of the application but unlike a MVC application where html views are returned I really want to have data just returned and consumed by the silverlight application. So each time I go to a new page in the silverlight application only the data is returned to populate it (I do not want to return a xaml page which has the data embedded in it). So all my application logic will be in the silverlight application.

Since our application will be a multi-user system, one of the requirements is that when showing a grid of data in the silverlight application the grid must be periodically updated  as other users add and remove records. Currently with the MVC app I have a timer which updates the grid with an Ajax call every few seconds.

I am not sure if I can reuse the mvc controllers and actions and just return data or whether I should go with RIA services as it may provide me with other richer functionality.

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIA does provide with richer functionality, but IMO lacks the very reusability (interop with jquery for example) you'd need here. See Tim Heuer's blog on how to use Silverlight as a View with MVC [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/02/09/silverlight-as-a-view-in-aspnet-mvc.aspx), and maybe add an extra parameter to your call's like (?mode=sl) and check for it in your controllers, so gather all your data you'll need for your views then

```
if (mode == "sl") return Json(data); 
else return View(data);
```

Of course, life is not this simple, you'll have problems with Child Actions, ViewModels, etc. But it's a start.

On the other hand if you're just doing CRUD operations, and have written almost no business logic into your controllers, then fire away with RIA! IMO, the most important thing of them all is DRY!!! (Don't repeat yourself) So if you have lot's of code in Controller then don't rewrite it around RIA in SL again!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My controllers will use a layer which has business logic that returns the correct data. This can be re-used in a RIA service I guess. What did you mean by  reusability (interop with jquery for example)?

Comment: I meant that RIA can only work with SOAP+SL, while a good controller can service HTML, XHTML requests from browser, Ajax, SL, anything.

Comment: Although I have spent sometime with the MVC app (using unity/learning JQuery etc as well as MVC 2), what we want is an app on the client and not pages being downloaded. So I think RIA is the way to go.

Comment: Instead of adding sl into the query line, i would recommend adding this into the request headier.  jQuery and Silverlight both allow for custom header information on the request.

Comment: @TDaver: Forgot to ask, what sort of problems will I have with Child actions, view models etc?

Comment: if you use viewmodel classes in mvc to help some display logic for the view, and your controller passes a VM to the view, you'll need to be able to deserialize the VM in SL as well (so not only model classes need to be "commoned"), and partial views may be called from views to provide additional infos, and of course when calling the controller from SL noone will "automatically" call the child actions, and if you've put up [ChildActionOnly] you can't call them directly either.

Answer (score 0):

Both?  :)

Create one or more repositories to contain your data IO and business logic and let your MVC actions and domain service methods surface what's needed.